# How to extract row from file and copy to another with bash

Tags: bash

How to extract specific row of file and save it in another file?
I have One file with 11 rows and I want to copy only row 4 to new file. File is in csv format

EDIT

i need to copy row not line. If the solution is to copy line then i need to copy 4th place from each line to new file. On that place is a 14 digit number and all 14 digits need to be copied

Comment: For many of us, "row" and "line" are synonymous in this context. Do you mean you want to extract a specific set of columns, by character position, or from a delimited format like CSV? Either way, it should be easy to find existing duplicates with many answers; this is a very common beginner FAQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452298/bash-command-to-print-column-at-specific-range-of-line-numbers

Comment: I have file that has 11 columns. From it i need only to copy column 4 to another file and from that file extract only last 8 digits from every line and have them send to web server.

Comment: I posted a second answer to the question I nominated as another duplicate. Since you only actually ask about the extraction, I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

awk command can be used for doing this

```
awk 'NR == LNUM' test.txt > test2.txt
```

this will copy line number represented by LNUM from test.txt to test2.txt

In your case command will be

```
awk 'NR == 4' test.txt > test2.txt
```

Comment: But won`t that copy line and not row?

Comment: If you want to copy 4th column of each line then you can use this command `awk '{print $4}' test.txt > test2.txt`. It will copy 4th column of each line into test2.txt. To copy any other column just change number after $.