# Use loop to extract rows from multiple files

Tags: loops, sed, output, extract

I am trying to create a loop that will allow me to extract rows 18 to 5773 (print all columns) from multiple files that follow the format CPMIR(1-6).sln and then output them to files numbered respectively, `batch[1-6].txt`

I've used the examples found online to come up with this code:

```
for i in {1..6}; do
    sed -n '{ '18,5773p;q' CPMIR'"${i}"'.sln }' > batch${i}.txt
done
```

but I am lost from here. Still new to coding and figuring it out as I go.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please add example input and output to your question.

Comment: YOu just needed to qualify your quit command, you have it running on every line, try `18,5773p;5773q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel "sed '1,17d;5773q' CPMIR{}.sln >batch{}.txt" ::: {1..6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452298/bash-command-to-print-column-at-specific-range-of-line-numbers): and got the below code to do the job

```
for i in {1..6}; do
  awk ' NR >=18 && NR <=5773 {print $0}' CPMIR${i}.sln > batch${i}.txt
done
```